# RSA Encryption with number theory

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I have a number theory class but my professor just put the homework about RSA encryption where we have absolutely no clue how to do, here's the two question, help appreciated:

a)  A word has been broken into blocks of two letters and converted to two-digit numbers using the correspondence:

$$a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3,o=4,k=5,f=6,h=7,l=8,j=9$$

The blocks are then encoded using the public key code with base 87 and exponent 19.  The coded message is $04/10$.  Find the word which was coded.

b) A public key code has base 143 and exponent 103.  It uses the following letter-to-number equivalents:

$$J=1,N=2,R=3,H=4,D=5,A=6,S=7,Y=8,T=9,O=0$$

A message has been converted to numbers and broken into blocks.  When coded using the above base and exponent the message sent is $10/03$.  Decode the message.

Comment: Allow me, how can you have absolutely no clue, you should have been exposed to RSA before this exercise.

Comment: Your professor must have a sense of humour, as the first word is *fool* (no joke). The second one is *JOHN*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part (a) really has two ciphertexts you have to decode: $04$ and $10$. I'll step you through the decoding of $04$. Using the notation from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Operation), you have $n=87$, $e=19$, and $c=04$.

To decode, you need to compute the decoding exponent $d=e^{-1} \text{ mod}$ [$\varphi(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). You can do that using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/exeucalg.html). You should get $d=3$.

Now the original message will be $m=c^d \text{ mod } n = 04^3 \text{ mod } 87 = 64 $. This corresponds to the letters **fo** by the key you gave in the question.

Try to apply a similar process to the others. Andreas gave the correct answers in the comments, so you can check your work against those.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be "FOOD"?

Comment: Oops. Yes, it should.